# ReflectionException in magento site loading time

Tags: magento2

> ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does
> not exist in
> /var/www/html/webstore-01.family.qa/public/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/webstore-01.family.qa/public/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(26):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #1
> /var/www/html/webstore-01.family.qa/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 2 /var/www/html/webstore-01.family.qa/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48):
>
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 3 /var/www/html/webstore-01.family.qa/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
>
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...',
> Array) #4
> /var/www/html/webstore-01.family.qa/public/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(235):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...',
> Array) #5 /var/www/html/webstore-01.family.qa/public/index.php(38):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 6 {main}

Comment: anyone help me  very urgent

Comment: Please explain your actually questions

Comment: run this command :- php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: sir i got only this error, already run this command but no chance

Comment: run again command and apply the permission chmod -R 777 var/ generated/

Comment: sie how to apply permission

Comment: after run this command i got this message Operation not permitted

Comment: chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ run this your magento  root

Comment: unfortunately no change

Comment: which error showing ??

Comment: chmod: changing permissions of ‘generated/code/Ecomteck/CustomerCustomAttributes/Model/Sales’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘generated/code/Ecomteck/CustomerCustomAttributes/Model/Sales/OrderFactory.php’: Operation not permitted

Comment: same as every module

Comment: this command run your root chmod -R 777 var generated ???